# Is there a way to pass a 2D array into a pthreads function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, pthreads

I am trying to understand pthreads and I am working on this project where I have to pass a 2d array via pthreads to a function that later would do some proccesing to the array.

I have tried to pass it with struct but I got confused.

```
#define rows 5
#define colums 5


void *maxthread(void *size )
{   
    int (*array)[rows][colums]
    ....
    ...
}



int main ()
{   
    
    int array[rows][colums];
    int p,P;
    pthread_t *thread;
    int i,j,r,c;
     
    
        printf("\n give numbers to array :\n");
     for(i=0;i< grammes;i++)
        {
        for(j=0;j< stiles;j++)
        {
            printf("element [%d,%d] : ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
 
    printf("\n matrix result :\n");
    for(i=0;i< rows;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j< colums;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");   
    }
    
    printf("give number of threads\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
    P=pthread_create(&thread[i][i],NULL,maxthread,(void *));
    
    return 0;
```

I expect to find the largest number in the array but first I have to pass the array through the pthread.

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense to me. You have a `thread *` pointer that isn't malloced and are using `&thread[i][i]` to index into this and attempt to create a thread. What is your intent here? Do you want a 2d array of threads? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: well am just trying things!! the main goal that i want to achive is to pass the array created by the user into the fuction via the pthread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good attempt; however, I recommend taking small steps and compiling frequently to avoid digging yourself too deeply into a state of confusion. As soon as you see an error, fix it before moving on further.

Given your use case (user-defined input), I recommend using dynamic memory allocation. This way, the user can specify any size matrix (as well as any number of threads). Secondly, since threads only accept one argument, it seems ideal to encapsulate matrix properties in a struct. There should be a pointer field to data as well as records for rows and columns, all of which may be user-specified using (more or less) your current input code.

After the argument struct is passed into the worker function, you'll need to cast it to the proper type. Be careful about modifying shared data here! You could add a mutex lock or semaphore to the matrix struct if multiple threads are going to attempt to modify it concurrently.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **data;
} matrix;

void *maxthread(void *arg) {   
    matrix m = *((matrix *)arg);

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            printf("[%2d]", m.data[i][j]);
        }

        puts("");
    }

    puts("");
    return NULL;
}

int main() {   
    int num_threads = 3; // or take user input
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    matrix m;
    m.rows = 11;         // or take user input
    m.cols = 8;
    m.data = malloc(sizeof(int *) * m.rows);

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        m.data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m.cols);

        for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
            m.data[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, maxthread, &m);
        threads[i] = thread;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
        free(m.data[i]);
    }

    free(m.data);
    return 0;
}
```

Output might be something like:

```
[ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0]
[ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7]
[ 0][ 2][ 4][ 6][ 8][10][12][14]
[ 0][ 3][ 6][ 9][12][15][18][21]
[ 0][ 4][ 8][12][16][20][24][28]
[ 0][ 5][10][15][20][25][30][35]
[ 0][ 6][12][18][24][30][36][42]
[ 0][ 7][14][21][28][35][42][49]
[ 0][ 8][16][24][32][40][48][56]
[ 0][ 9][18][27][36][45][54][63]
[ 0][10][20][30][40][50][60][70]

[ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0]
[ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7]
[ 0][ 2][ 4][ 6][ 8][10][12][14]
[ 0][ 3][ 6][ 9][12][15][18][21]
[ 0][ 4][ 8][12][16][20][24][28]
[ 0][ 5][10][15][20][25][30][35]
[ 0][ 6][12][18][24][30][36][42]
[ 0][ 7][14][21][28][35][42][49]
[ 0][ 8][16][24][32][40][48][56]
[ 0][ 9][18][27][36][45][54][63]
[ 0][10][20][30][40][50][60][70]

[ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0][ 0]
[ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6][ 7]
[ 0][ 2][ 4][ 6][ 8][10][12][14]
[ 0][ 3][ 6][ 9][12][15][18][21]
[ 0][ 4][ 8][12][16][20][24][28]
[ 0][ 5][10][15][20][25][30][35]
[ 0][ 6][12][18][24][30][36][42]
[ 0][ 7][14][21][28][35][42][49]
[ 0][ 8][16][24][32][40][48][56]
[ 0][ 9][18][27][36][45][54][63]
[ 0][10][20][30][40][50][60][70]
```

Comment: Thank you for yout help! may i ask what is the purpose of this line you wrote:m.data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m.cols);

Comment: Check out an [overview of dynamic memory in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). `int **` is a pointer to an array of arrays of integers. So we need to allocate memory for the outer array, which is the size of an integer pointer times the number of rows, then, for each row, we need to allocate memory for an array the size of an integer times the number of columns in the row. Play around with mallocing a 1d array first, then upgrade to 2d.